# C# Iterate 'Default Document' IIS 7 feature

Tags: c#, iis-7

How can I iterate through file names in the 'Default Document' IIS feature for an application in C#?

I am using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using its "loosely" typed model, basically for reading it for Default Web Site would look like:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Configuration webConfig = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");
    ConfigurationSection section = webConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/defaultDocument");
    foreach (ConfigurationElement item in section.GetCollection("files"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item["value"]);
    }
}
```

You can also generate strongly-typed wrappers for collections and entries you want to use frequently which makes it a lot cleaner and prevents mistakes, that would make it look like:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Configuration webConfig = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");
    DefaultDocumentSection section = (DefaultDocumentSection)webConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/defaultDocument", typeof(DefaultDocumentSection));
    foreach (FileElement item in section.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
}
```

And for that to work you need the following "strongly-typed-wrappers":

```
public class DefaultDocumentSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private FilesCollection _files;
    public FilesCollection Files
    {
        get
        {
            if (_files == null)
            {
                _files = (FilesCollection)base.GetCollection("files", typeof(FilesCollection));
            }

            return _files;
        }
    }

}
public class FilesCollection : ConfigurationElementCollectionBase<FileElement>
{
    protected override FileElement CreateNewElement(string elementTagName)
    {
        return new FileElement();
    }
}

public class FileElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public string Value { get { return (string)base["value"]; } }
}
```